# strange 500 error when submit PHP

Tags: jquery, forms

I found an error about my form send.php, after using of jquery.

I have send.php and class.phpmailer.php in /form folder.

After submit there is new window with 'nok' which is

```
if ($error) {
    exit('nok');
} 

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    exit('nok');
}
```

Any ideas where I have to start looking for solution?

Comment: Turn on `display errors` **OR** look at it locally in your webserver; it'll give you more information about the error.

Comment: I see only: 
[Fri Jan 17 14:39:02 2014] [core:error]  End of script output before headers: send.php

Comment: Check the permissions of your php files. They should be minimum 705